# Unity: Player too close to wall "defies" gravity [Video]

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a little platformer where the player can jump. The jumping works fine, The player jumps high up in the air and falls back down depending on the gravity that I set to it. However, as soon as the player goes over an edge where he can fall down afterwards, his physics seem to get stuck entierly. Instead of falling, he sort of slowly decends as if he was made from leafs or so.

I found out that this also occurs once the player hits a sideways wall. It looks like once you go over an edge the player sort of touches the side of the wall for a second and this kills its physics.

I have recorded this issue here:

https://youtu.be/CE-W4wmMqcA

These are my player settings:

[image]

I also tried addin 2D physics to both the wall and the blayer and there set everything to 0. This did alter the effets a little but was far from solving it...

Also, my fixed update, where I jump (catch the bool from update, do physics in fixed:)

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    currentPlayerSpeed = rb.velocity.x;

    if (moveLeft)
    {
        rb.AddForce((Vector2.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime) - rb.velocity, ForceMode2D.Force);

    }
    if (moveRight)
    {
        rb.AddForce((Vector2.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime) - rb.velocity, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }

    if (jump)
    {

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            isGrounded = false;

            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * (jumpHeight * counterForJumpHeight) * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jump = false;

            anim.SetBool("bool_anim_isJumping", true);
        }

        if (timer != null)
            timer.Stop();

        counterForJumpHeight = jumpMulitMin;

        jumpAlreadCharging = false;

    }

    if (!moveLeft && !moveRight) // if no movement input is happening
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            StopVelocity();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any friction or something on the terrain? From the video, It feels like your terrain is causing the issue. Although in `0:01` it works fine in the first obstacle i am a bit confused.

Comment: no friction set. once i did, i set it to 0 which helped a bit but not enough... :(

Comment: This is really weird. Can you in the beginning of the game instantiate player object in the air. Lets see if it will fall properly. if it does, it means  problem is in the terrain or jump script.

Comment: okay great! instantiating hte playeer in the air makes him drop just fine. so it has to be another thing.. :S

Comment: Did my answer solve the problem? Any updates?

Comment: damnit it did ! :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i think i figured it out when you are falling both your `moveLeft` and `moveRight` variables are false so you are calling `StopVelocity` and this if statement is executed.

```
if (!moveLeft && !moveRight) // if no movement input is happening
{
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        StopVelocity();
    }

}
```

This causes that weird behavior. Since you did not jump but only fall `isGrounded` is true as well :)

Comment: AWESOME! Totally correct. I wrote that function because I wanted the player not to instantly stop once no more input is happening but to sort of do a couple more steps. turned out that RBs already have a linear drag paramater that does that for you. Simply removing my function and playing around with the drag (and therefore the speed again) fixed it. thank you so much !